# MySQL Infinite Loop

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am somewhat inexperienced with MySQL.

I am trying to merge two tables according to an ISR id number and then insert that data into another table, adr.  I am running a SQL query on a MySQL database in Workbench 5.2 and my query takes less than a second if I limit my code as follows:

```
TRUNCATE adr;

INSERT into adr
(SELECT drug08q1.isr, drug08q1.drugname, reac08q1.pt 
FROM drug08q1
INNER JOIN reac08q1
ON drug08q1.isr = reac08q1.isr LIMIT 0,2815);

SELECT * FROM adr;
```

If I increment the limit to:

```
LIMIT 0,20816
```

The SQL will say it's running forever and never finish.  I have no idea why incrementing the LIMIT beyond some random threshold will result in an infinite loop.  What could I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: How do you know it's running forever and never finishes?  Did you wait until the end of time?  Have you built indexes on `drug08q1.isr` and `reac08q1.isr`?

Comment: How many rows are in drug08q1 and reac08q1? Have you already looked into [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html)? And finally, if you run the select alone, does it take "forever" too?

Comment: Thank you eggyyal!  It was a simple fix to index the ISR's of each table.  I didn't think the data was large enough to need this, but it ran the query in 33 seconds.